# cocos2d-x ClippingNode jaggies

Tags: android, macos, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I try to make clippingNode with circle stencil, but the result is the edge is not smooth
Tried with DrawNode.drawDot and a Sprite as stencil, same result

I also tried with many threshold numbers, still the same, could be worse.. this image is using 0.05

Is there anyway to make the edge smoother?

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.5

[image: ClippingNode]

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution provided in [this forum](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-v3-anti-aliasing-for-primitives/20548/9) by using anti-aliasing:

```
const char* ccPositionColorLengthTexture_frag = STRINGIFY(

\n#ifdef GL_ES\n
\n#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable\n

varying mediump vec4 v_color;
varying mediump vec2 v_texcoord;
\n#else\n
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
\n#endif\n

void main()
{
 \n#if defined GL_OES_standard_derivatives\n
gl_FragColor = v_color*smoothstep(0.0, length(fwidth(v_texcoord)), 1.0 - length(v_texcoord));\n    
\n#else\n
gl_FragColor = v_color*step(0.0, 1.0 - length(v_texcoord));
 \n#endif\n
}
);
```

with some adjustments like

changed the:

```
 dot->drawDot(end, DOT_RADIUS / 2.0, color);
```

to:

```
dot->drawSegment(start, end, DOT_RADIUS / 2, color);
```